# DataAnnotationsExtensions.Numeric with commas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, data-annotations, cultureinfo, numeric

I am working on a model (in a MVC3 project) that uses a latitude and longitude attributes, they are currently set as a [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Numeric]. But this causes a "The field Latitude must be a number." error when i enter a number with a comma (50,01) even if the user has a culture that uses this kind of annotation (nl-BE for example).

What i am asking if there is a way to configure [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Numeric] that it does allow comma with any kind of culture, or a better way to specify a number than [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Numeric]?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with RegularExpressions

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9,-\.]+$", ErrorMessage = "Format is Invalid")]
```

Comment: I have done this, but the data-val-number that gives the previous error still exists (I have removed [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Numeric]), do you know a way to remove data-val-number?

Comment: Are you sure its because of the data-val-number? Maybe it's related to local settings (try dot instead of comma)

Comment: I am trying to make it except both ways . and ,

Comment: I solved it by doing ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear(); thank you for the help.